# Rest Service proxy creation error

Tags: rest, resteasy

I made a Rest Service and when I access it from an application, I get this RunTimeError

> You must define a @Consumes type on your client method or interface, or supply a default

Below is my code for creating the proxy

```
UsersInterface proxy = ProxyFactory.create(UsersInterface.class,
                                ApplicationConfig.getSAPlatformURL(),
                                this.createExecutor());
```

I am a beginner in Rest Services, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually the problem of taking the input.
Try to use the following annotation

```
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

You can put it over your class or over methods.

More info is avialable here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqqr/index.html

Comment: Wondering why I'm getting this for @GET method.